# ACRA custom log reporter

Tags: android, logging, crash, acra, bugsense

I'm using ACRA with bugsense.com in conjunction for taking bug reports. Can I use them to send my arbitrary messages from an app?

I want it send user's wrong behavior to bugsense server. Is the only way to do this is generate Exception?

I'm not sure is it good idea at all. What do you use to save your Logs?

EDIT:
I've completly migrated to Bugsense tracker. It has ability to send custom handled exceptions. Easy to implement, one line of the code only.

[Log Handled Exceptions](https://www.bugsense.com/docs/android#log-handled-exceptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember, but I think you can use ACRA to send report even when the app don't crash. Look at the developer site: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception